# Best practices regarding the creation of custom widgets?

Tags: functions, customization, theme-development, widgets, sidebar

I am creating a theme, and I need to create and register a couple of custom widgets for my sidebar.

I need to extend the widget class (for every widget) to do this, which produces a metric ton of code. This seems to really litter my functions.php - especially since I have 5+ custom widgets at this point.

I was wondering, if there are recommended guidelines for how to best include custom widgets in your theme? I have been scouring the developers handbook, but can't find any suggestions of where it typically makes sense to store your widget class extensions?

Comment: Write a custom plugin: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: @shanebp It is a good suggestion - and probably better in terms of inter-theme operability. However, in this case, I would like to have these widgets included in my theme if possible!

Comment: Sorry - in your theme is probably best done with a custom class and/or template-part + custom css.  Find a free theme that includes a widget and examine the process. Take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally, you can place the widget code anywhere inside your theme files (except template files) and include them from `functions.php` file.

> functions.php is the only file that WordPress includes when you theme
>   is active

There is no best practice where you put them, but that doesn't mean you should mess things up. It is best to keep each of your widget code inside a separate file.

---

### To keep things organized, you can put each of your widget files inside any of the following folder of your theme:

- `/includes/`
- `/widgets/`
- `/includes/widgets/`

---

### Naming widget file:

You can only register a custom widget by extending `WP_Widget` class. That indicates you need to write a class for each widget. Considering this, your widget files should be named with a class prefix. Like: `class-widget-one.php` PHP file prefixed with a class indicates this file contain only one class.

---

### Registering widgets:

It's better to register all of you widgets from `functions.php`. That's makes it easy understand how many custom widget your theme providers, and where they are located.

```php
function wpse366458_register_widgets() {
    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/widgets/class-widget-one.php' );
    register_widget( 'Theme_Widget_One' );

    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/widgets/class-widget-two.php' );
    register_widget( 'Theme_Widget_Two' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpdocs_register_widgets' );
```

---

### Reusing codes over multiple widgets:

Now it completely depends on your needs and taste. You can -

- use Trait class and methods will be available inside your current widget class. ie: `get_page_choices()`.
- use class with static methods. ie: `Prefix_Widget_Helper::get_page_choices()`
- use functions. ie: `prefix_get_page_choices()`, `prefix_sanitize_something()`

Comment: I would just like to say, that this is a wonderful answer. I ended up coming to a similar conclusion before you posted it, but something like this should be the honestly be a go-to guideline for theme developers, since it would also make taking over projects from other developers less of a hassle. Thank you for this!

Comment: @p01ntbr34k You are welcome. I am glad it helped.